# What are the transformers mean?

Tags: dart

I have a yaml file with following content:

```
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
```

What does platform_directives means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformers are a feature of the `pub` tool.

Transformer can transform existing code before it is delivered to the browser.
`dart2js` that transpiles Dart code to JS is also available as transformer (also available as standalone tool)

A transformer is a Dart program that is registered in `pubspec.yaml` (like shown in your question) and then executed by `pub serve` or `pub build` for every source file. A transformer can then take such a source file and modify it before it's passed to the next transformer or to the browser (`pub serve` or to a file on the disk (`pub build`). Also new files can be generated.

- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers
- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers
- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/examples
- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/aggregate